# Is there a way to cast a System.Type as implementing interfaces (including new())?

Tags: c#, types, interface, casting

I have the following two method definitions:

- `static T DeserializeNormal<T>(string s)`
- `static T DeserializeSpecial<T>(string s) where T: IMessage<T>, new()`

I would like to write a method with the following signature
`static T Deserialize<T>(string s)`

the new method would simply check if T implements `IMessage<T>` and `new()`, and if so, calls `DeserializeSpecial<T>()`, and if not, calls `DeserializeNormal<T>()`.

I've run into two problems:

1. Is there a way to check if a `System.Type` implements `new()`? I don't seem to able to accomplish that with the pattern `(System.Type)typeof(T).GetInterfaces().GetValue(0) == typeof(IMessage);` because `new()` is not actually an interface.
2. Is there a way to cast `typeof(T)` to assert to the compiler that it *does* in fact implement `IMessage<T>` and `new()`? As it stands, I can check for `IMessage`, but then attempting to call `DeserializeSpecial<T>()` gives me a compiler error that `T` does not implement `IMessage`, even though I just checked. All the casting behavior I can find is for *objects*, not `System.Type`.

Comment: You don't need to check for `new()`. The compiler will show error if you are using a type which does not have a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Because the function's type parameter is generic, the compiler can't know whether or not the type has a parameterless constructor, because the type parameter has no value until runtime.

Comment: You're conflating intent. If you are using generics, the compiler will give you assurances, as Chetan pointed out. You typically only need to check Type for things like a parameterless constructor if you are NOT strongly-typing a method call.

Comment: @riizade, that is simply incorrect.

Comment: Type checking at compile time is the purpose of Generics and `where` constraint. https://dotnetfiddle.net/AzoSkG

Comment: What I mean to say is that my previous statement applies in a function signature without a `where new()` constraint on the generic type. Everyone is right to point out that if I apply a type constraint `where new()`, the compiler knows that I can use `new T()` to construct an instance of the type.

However, that misses the point. My point is that in a function *without* the `where new()` constraint, I want to check whether `new()` is available *at runtime*, *dynamically each time the function is called*, which necessarily *does not* involve the compiler, because they are runtime checks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifying comment, I believe what you are trying to accomplish is that you want to be able to check if a type has a parameterless constructor at runtime, simulating the same behavior as the `where new()` constraint.

Obviously this is far less efficient if done at runtime, but you absolutely can check for a parameterless constructor.

```
if (typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes) is not null)
{
    // call method 
}
```

This of course creates other issues, such as potentially needing to dynamically create the type if it does not already exist, and it prevents you from being able to call `DeserializeSpecial<T>` without additional reflection.